# webpack's sass-loader do not find foundation scss file without underline prefix

Tags: css, node.js, sass, webpack

Recently, i was working on rapid frontend development toolchain with **webpack**, **sass**, **bower** and **foundation5**.

I encounter a problem:
sass-loader only load scss file with **underline prefix**.

### Environments

> node v0.12.4
>  webpack 1.9.11
>  node-sass 3.2.0
>   sass-loader 1.0.2 
>  os gentoo 3.18

### webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var getDir = function() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
};

module.exports = {
  // webpack options 
  context: getDir('./src'),

  entry: {
    test: "./style/test.scss"
  },

  output: {
    path: getDir('./build'),
    filename: "[name].js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: "style!css!sass?outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=" + getDir('bower_components', 'foundation', 'scss')}
    ]
  },

  progress: false, // Don't show progress 
  // Defaults to true 

  failOnError: true, // don't report error to grunt if webpack find errors 
  // Use this if webpack errors are tolerable and grunt should continue 

  watch: true, // use webpacks watcher 
  // You need to keep the grunt process alive 

  keepalive: false, // don't finish the grunt task 
  // Use this in combination with the watch option 

  devtool: 'eval'
};
```

### test.scss

```
@import "settings";
@import "normalize";
@import "foundation/components/panels";
@import "foundation/components/type";
```

### settings.scss

```
empty file
```

### project layout

- bower_componets
- package.json
- src
--  style
---   test.scss
---   settings.scss
- webpack.config.js

When i run **webpack** command, i got error:

> ERROR in
>   ../~/css-loader!../~/sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&includePaths[]=/home/ray/test/testsassloader/bower_co
>   mponents/foundation/scss!./style/test.scss
>   Module build failed:  @import "normalize";
>          ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ./_normalize.scss
>         in /home/ray/test/testsassloader/src/style/test.scss (line 2, column 9)  @ ./style/test.scss 4:14-220

Though, i copy **bower_components/foundation/scss/normalize.scss** to **bower_components/foundation/scss/_normalize.scss**, it works.

So i try to run by node-sass without _normalize.scss:

```
 ./node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass --include-path=$(pwd)/bower_components/foundation/scss/ src/style/test.scss
```

**It works!!!**

I conclude that it was the webpack resolver cause the problem!!
Any one could help me solve the problem? Did the copy do the right job?

Answer (score 2):

At webpack.config add the bower components dir to resolve modulesDirectories,

```
{
...
      resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['./bower_components', 'node_modules']
      },
      module: {
      ...
      }
...
}
```

Then, import foundation like so at test.scss:

```
@import "settings";
@import "~foundation/scss/normalize";
@import "~foundation/scss/foundation";
```

Comment: It is a bug that fixed @1.0.3. Your solution works but the scss files can not be portable without webpack

Comment: Hi! I ran into this same problem, however I've included my `./sass` folder in the `modulesDirectives` array, but still getting that error. Mind a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058357/webpack-not-understanding-import-statement-in-my-sass-files