# Webpack2 not understanding @import statement in my SASS files (How to compile SASS with webpack2?)

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack, webpack-2, sass-loader

[**Using Webpack 2**](https://webpack.js.org) and [**sass-loader**](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) 4.11

`webpack --config webpack.config.js`

[image]

Here is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var sass = require("./sass/lifeleveler.scss");

module.exports = {
    entry: './dist/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'lifeleveler.app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000,
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, './sass')
                ],
                loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    sassLoader: {
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./sass")]
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ['./sass'],
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", "scss"]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

---

Note when I tried this at the top of my config:

```
var css = require("!raw-loader!sass-loader!./sass/lifeleveler.scss");
var css = require("!css-loader!sass-loader!./sass/lifeleveler.scss");
```

Got this error:

> Error: Cannot find module '!raw-loader!sass-loader!./sass/lifeleveler.scss'

Which is why I went with just this: `var sass = require("./sass/lifeleveler.scss");`

---

And my lifeleveler.scss file ([from my SASS project starter kit](https://github.com/leongaban/sass-smacss)):

```
@import "vendors/normalize";    // Normalize stylesheet
@import "vendors/reset";        // Reset stylesheet
@import "modules/base";         // Load base files
@import "modules/defaults";     // Defaults elements
@import "modules/inputs";       // Inputs & Selects
@import "modules/buttons";      // Buttons
@import "modules/layout";       // Load Layouts
@import "modules/svg";          // Load SVG
@import "modules/queries";      // Media Queries
```

Any finally my folder structure, do you see any glaring issues?

[image]

[I found this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31004689/webpacks-sass-loader-do-not-find-foundation-scss-file-without-underline-prefix), however I added my `./sass` path to the `modulesDirectories` array and still getting the error.

After more digging I also found [this Github issue and solution here](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/344), but his fix didn't work for me either :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I reproduced your issue here and was able to fix it.

First of all, you need to change your webpack configuration file. Some points:

1. put yout `scss` loader inside `rules` option and separate each loader into an object (like [this](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader));
2. get rid of the line `var sass = require("./sass/lifeleveler.scss");` at the top of the configuration. The file should be called from your entrypoint JS. In this case: `dist/main.js`. At this point (before reading the config), webpack is not configured to load any stuff. That's causing the error you showed.
3. get rid of `sassLoader.includePaths` and `resolve.modulesDirectories`, as they are not valid **webpack 2** keys.

**Webpack 2** configuration structure is a bit different from **Webpack 1** (you can check a official migration guide [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/))..

The working `webpack.config.js` file would be something like this:

```
var path = require('path');


module.exports = {
    entry: './dist/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'lifeleveler.app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    watch: true,
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000,
        ignored: /node_modules/
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "sass")
                ],             
                use: [
                     { loader: "style-loader" },
                     { loader: "css-loader" },
                     { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", "scss"]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

In your `main.js`, now you can require your scss file calling:

```
require('../sass/lifeleveler.scss'); //assuming main.js is at ./dist
```

Make sure you've npm installed `style-loader`, `css-loader`, `node-sass` and `sass-loader`.

Now compiles correctly!

Comment: Ah thank you for that explanation! :D Got it working... I didn't realize that's how webpack worked. I see now that my styles are actually in the JS! Combined with templateCache later, I guess everything will be in 1 file. Cool :) 20 hrs before I can check this!

Answer (score 3):

Try this configuration to your `webpack.config.js`

```
...
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /.s?css$/,
      use: ExtractTextWebpack.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              importLoader: true
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              plugins: [
                ... // fill your config
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              ... // fill your config
            }
          }
        ]
      })
    }
  ]
},
plugins: [
  new ExtractTextWebpack({
    filename: 'bundle.css'
  })
]
...
```

This is the version of dependencies you need.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "beta",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
  }
```

don't forget to require your `style.scss` root to your entry file.

**Example:**
in your `./dist/main.js` require your sass by writing`require('../sass/liveleverer.scss')`

Comment: Thanks! +1 I tried mrlew's first and liked his extra info